# How do I tell what computer added a file to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I want to be able to understand which computer added files to Dropbox.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the file and view "Previous versions". Version 1 will show the name of the computer (as you've defined it with the Dropbox client) where it originated (or "web" if you've uploaded it directly).